# Getting the content of a window to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, sendkeys, pywinauto

I'm trying to use `HwndWrapper.Texts()` which supposedly "Returns the text for each item of this control" but it only returns the tile which is u'Fight plan settings dialog', why is this happening?

The code is this:

```
prog=application.Application()
prog.connect_(path=r'D:\Thesis\Euroscope\Euroscope.exe')
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Fight plan setting dialog', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = prog.window_(handle=w_handle)
c=prog.Fightplansettingsdialog.Texts()
```

Here is a screen of the window I'm trying to copy from:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/newpicturewe.png/

I spent the afternoon reading the pywinauto documentation and i can't manage to find a way to get the content of a window like the one before into a text file(except clicking and copying each item with `DoubleClick()` and then `Ctrl+C` with TypeKeys which is way too long). Any ideas?

Edit: Also, I found out that `PrintControlIdentifiers` can't be easily saved to a strings file. Doing c=prog.PrintControlIdentifiers() returns None when i ask for c. Any way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get all texts from a window by running through all children.

```
all_texts = []
for child in window.Children():
  all_texts.extend(child.Texts())
all_texts = filter(lambda t:t, all_texts) # clear empty texts
```

By the way, it seems the window should be called 'Flight plan...' :-)

PS.
I am happy to help a virtual controller!

UKHH - MDN91

Comment: Damn thats exactly what i wanted,thank you! Just so i understand though... what does the "filter(lambda t:t,all_texts)" means?

Also,what is the order of the reading in child.Texts()?because it starts the reading on the IFR instead of in the Callsign

Yeah i noticed that "Fight plan" too. It's a Euroscope error :D

Comment: (1) .Texts() may return a list with empty text/s, e.g. ['some text', '']. It just clears lots of '', '', '',... lambda t:t returns False for ''(empty string). (2) the order is not specified anywere. So if you are looking for a concrete style, make an ordered table with field names and dump texts according this table. (3) A funny mistake

Comment: what module i need to import to test this one?